# random numbers not so random

Tags: c++, random

I have a method in a class as follows...

```
class foo{
   int bar::randomNum10to50(){
      srand (time(NULL));
      int random10to50 = rand()%50+10; 
      return random10to50;
   }
}
```

However when I call it from main (just to check the output, because i wasn't getting the behaviour from the program I expected) like so....

```
foo create;
for (int i=0; i<20;i++){
    cout<<create.randomNum10to50()<<endl;
}
```

it's exactly the same number every time it's run (ie, 9,9,9,9,9,....; next run: 43,43,43,43,.....) I don't know what is going wrong.
The code runs very quickly so I was thinking that MIGHT be the issue but I don't see why there wouldn't be a difference even slightly between the 20 iterations of it. Any thoughts are appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: "9,9,9,9,9" was a 'typo', right? I'm just wondering because you should only get results in the range of 10 to 50..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to call `srand()` *once*, *outside* of the randomizer function. Otherwise, you re-seed the random number generator each time with the exact same time value, producing the same initial "random" value.

Answer (score 6):

You are calling `srand()` with the same seed every loop iteration, since the time doesn't actually have, um, time to change. Make sure to call it only once and everything should work.

Answer (score 3):

Cody Gray already says what you're doing wrong here, but here's an example of doing this with the `<random>` library:

```
#include <random>

std::mt19937 make_seeded_engine() {
    std::random_device r;
    std::seed_seq seed{r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r()};
    return std::mt19937(seed);
}

class foo {
   std::mt19937 engine;

public:
   foo() : engine(make_seeded_engine()) {}

   int randomNum10to50(){
      return std::uniform_int_distribution<>(10,50)(engine); 
   }
};

foo create;
for (int i=0; i<20;i++){
    cout << create.randomNum10to50() << '\n';
}
```

Note that `rand()%50 + 10` produces numbers in the range 10 to 59, not 10 to 50. uniform_int_distribution is better because the range you give it is the range you get, so you're less likely to mess it up. Also using uniform_int_distribution gives you unbiased results whereas `rand()%50+10` has some slight bias.

---

If you have a compiler with a bit more C++11 support you can do:

```
class foo{
   std::mt19937 engine = make_seeded_engine();

public:
   int randomNum10to50(){
      return std::uniform_int_distribution<>(10,50)(engine); 
   }
};
```

Comment: nice! Thanks! I may end up using that. Good info!

Comment: Note your compiler will need to support C++11 to do this otherwise you can use boost which is where `<random>` came from I believe.

Comment: @AJG85 Yeah, it uses some C++11, but I was careful to limit it to what's widely supported. VS11 and gcc as far back as 4.5 can run this. But I think I'll add a version that uses more C++11 to clean it up a little...

Comment: Since VC10 actually but it's still worth noting as I know people using VC6 still.

Comment: @AJG85 ah, neat. I had thought random_device wasn't in until 11. Anyway VC6 hardly even counts as a C++ compiler. I hear it's fast at compiling whatever language that is though ; )

Comment: Fast like a dinosaur. Took well over an hour to compile Intel CSF with Boost 1.33 many years ago when I first used mt19937 engine for randoms ;-)